# Can't get materialui input or textfield aligned horizontally

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

```
import {Input} from 'material-ui';

import Select from 'react-select';
```

No matter how I change margins or padding and put them inside divs. Material UI textfield or input has this weird space on top of it relative to other elements. So I can't get them align horizontally with other components. I believe it is the empty label of Input that is occupying the space. Is it a common thing or am I missing something obivious? Thanks.

```
<Select
      className="min-w-256 inline-block"
      name="form-field-name"
      placeholder="Item Name"
      value={this.state.currentRecord.itemName}
      onChange={this.handleItemNameChange}
      options={this.state.itemNameList}
/>

<Input
     label = {null}
     className="max-w-128 inline-block "
     id="input-quantity"
     value={this.state.currentRecord.quantity}
     onChange={this.handleCurrentRecordTextChange('quantity')}
/>
```

Comment: material-ui version you are using ? is it v0.20.1 or v1.x ?

Comment: it is 1.0.0-beta.47

Comment: You should provide a little bit more code including styles. Please consider adding a simple demo which will expose your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The component styles are probably overriding your classes, Material-UI's styling solution needs to be configured if you are gonna use global css. Checkout https://material-ui.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-class-names for more info.